sending FCM to device by Firebase Cloud Functions with python
I have the following server code in python stored in firebase cloud functions
import firebase_admin
import google.cloud.firestore as t
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore


from firebase_admin import messaging
from firebase_functions import firestore_fn



cred = credentials.Certificate(my credentials stuff to give it permission to access database as admin)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()



@firestore_fn.on_document_created(document=r"Notifications/{id}")
def send_notification(event: firestore_fn.Event[firestore_fn.DocumentSnapshot | None]) -> None:
    sent_to_device = "my-device-unique-id"

    # notification = messaging.Notification(
    # title="You have a new follower!",
    # body="Someone is now following you.",
    # )
    doc_ref = db.collection("Users")
    doc_ref.add({"first": "Ada", "last": "Lovelace", "born": 1815})

    msgs = [
        messaging.Message(token=sent_to_device, data={'data': 'hello'})
    ]
    messaging.send_each(msgs)    

    return

so what it does is to listen to a collection in my database in firebase cloud. If a user follows someone else, a document is created in notifications. it will store the device number from gettoken(). When a notification document is created, when a user follows other user, it calls the server function. However, I do not get the notification in my android device.
I tested the server function by adding a temporary document to other collection in my database, by using the db variable, and it does work. The function does responds to when a user follows another user.
It does work from the firebase console. I can send a fcm to my device and it does get send.
here is my android manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <application
        android:label="appname"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        
<service
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>


        <receiver
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>


I am trying to send a notification by running my application from the web, not from another device. Could that be the problem?
I also have read that I need to ask user for notification permission, which I already did in Flutter
      Timer.run(() {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isDismissible: true,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Notifications'),
                actions: [
                  FutureBuilder(
                      future: Permission.notification.request(),
                      builder:
                          (context, AsyncSnapshot<PermissionStatus> snapshot) {
                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () => snapshot.data!.isGranted,
                                child: Text('Confirm'))
                          ],
                        );
                      })

I have near 0 experience with python so maybe my syntax is wrong?

Is this really in your code: sent_to_device = "my-device-unique-id"? If so, that explains why it doesn't work: you'll need to put the device token of the device you want to send the message to in there.

oh no. I was using events.params['deviceNumber'], but it throws a error saying the key does not exists. So I just inserted the string value as given by getToken(), but I hide it here so no one can see it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55495695/12211545 This answer solved my problem. The answer explains it pretty good! One thing I noticed is that the firebase documentation request this to be added to the manifest file 



 but mine is different, i got that from someone here on overstack. It was closing the app as soon as a fcm was received. If anyone finds this helpful!
